# Jquery ajax disable submit button until form has been completed

Tags: jquery

Below I have my code for displaying and handling my form. The script work fine but now I need to disable the submit button until the fields on the form have been completed. Which is the correct way to do this?

My script

```
$( function() {
$(".input").val("");
var dialog1, form,
dialog1 = $( "#dialog-form1" ).dialog({
dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-content1',
autoOpen: false,
maxHeight: 500,
height: 500,
width: 800,
modal: true,
buttons: [
{
 text: "Reset",
 click: function() {
   $('#Form1').trigger("reset");
   $("#imageviewdiv").hide();
   $("#pcicon").hide();
   $('#Preview4').html("");
   $('#previewtext').html("");
   $('#imageis').hide();
   $('#image_position_portrait').hide();
 }},
 {
 text: "Cancel",
 click: function() {
   $('#Form1').trigger("reset");
   $("#imageviewdiv").hide();
   $("#pcicon").hide();
   $('#Preview4').hide();
   $(this).dialog("close");
}},
{
text: "Submit",
click: function() {
var form = document.getElementById("Form1");
   var fd = new FormData(form );
   $.ajax({
     url: "insert_new_promotion.php",
     data: fd,
     cache: false,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function (dataofconfirm) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
  $(this).dialog("close");
 }}
]
});
$( "#new-record" ).button().on( "click", function() {
  dialog1.dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Just disable the button before Ajax `POST` and re-enable it on the `success` handler.

Comment: @ jom hi and thanks for your reply, disable and re-enable, how and where?

Comment: There are several ways, have a look at [this one](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#callback-functions). You should be able to disable the button on `beforeSend` and re-enable it when you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable the button right before the Ajax call or on `beforeSend` callback. Refer to the docs for [callback function queues](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#callback-functions). The [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is what allows you to get the clicked button.

```
$("#dialog-form1").dialog({
  dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-content1',
  autoOpen: false,
  maxHeight: 500,
  height: 500,
  width: 800,
  modal: true,
  buttons: [
    {
      // Other buttons
    }, 
    {
      text: "Submit",
      click: function (e) {
        var button = e.target;
        var form = document.getElementById("Form1");
        var fd = new FormData(form );

        // Either disable it here or on `beforeSend` callback.
        button.disabled = true;

        $.ajax({
          url: "insert_new_promotion.php",
          data: fd,
          cache: false,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          //beforeSend: function() {
          //  button.disabled = true;
          //},
          type: 'POST',
          success: function (dataofconfirm) {
            // You may not need to re-enable the button since you are reloading the page anyway
            button.disabled = false;

            window.location.reload();
          }
        });

        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handler just give all the text fields a common class and check that if all of these are filled or not

```
$('.input-fields').on('change',function(){
    var disable = false
   $('.input-fields').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
         disable = true
      }

    }

    $('#button-id').prop('disabled',disable)

})
```

**Second Method**

Add `data-toggle="validator" novalidate="true"` this in `<form>` tag and add `required` to required fields it will automatically disable the submit button

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Hi, I think the issue I have is because the submit button is not directly embedded in the form as a "form button", it;s generated by my script which is why I think I am having problems, any ideas.

Comment: Still you can implement this by setting ID dynamically of the button while creating. How much buttons are you creating on runtime ?